# How do I deploy to Websphere developer server 8.5 via Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, websphere

How does one deploy a web app from Eclipse Mars to a local install of IBM Websphere Application Server Developer 8.5 ?

I installed the app server from IBM's Installation Manager, upon completion it says its location is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01

I tested the app itself using the "First Steps" window which popped up after install, and it looks like it is running fine.

Now, I want to test creating a simple hello world web application in Eclipse Mars, and be able to deploy it to this installed Websphere instance and be able to debug (stop at breakpoints). However, I can't seem to figure this part out.

When I go to my Servers tab in Eclipse and attempt to add a Websphere server, I didn't have any options. So I started downloading some IBM Websphere Developer Tools that I could find. I managed to now have these options for adding server:
"WebSphere Application Server Liberty"
"WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5"

I tried using both, but they don't seem to be compatible with my installed version of WebSphere, because I keep getting the error of "The WebSphere Application Server traditional installation directory is not correct." when I try to plug in the Installation directory.

I suspect I should have a separate option for
"WebSphere Application Server developer V8.5" 
or such, however no matter what I search for online, in the Eclipse marketplace, in the Eclipse sites, I can't find anything to install that gives me that option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5" and point it to the installation root not the profile root - so to `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer` in your case.

For the future, it is not recommended to install WebSphere in the `Program Files (x86)` folder, I'd suggest something simpler like `c:\IBM`.

Comment: It doesn't like it - see screen shot: http://imgur.com/kIdFS7c And it auto picked that program files folder b default

Comment: @Trant Are you sure that your user that is using Eclipse has writable permissions to `Program Files` folder? Are you using administrative user? I know that this is default, but I'm telling you what is best practice , not default ;-). Try running Eclipse with `Run As Administrator`.

Comment: oh ok, got it. But run as administrator is not making any difference to the Add Server dialog - he still doesnt like my AppServer folder. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below link [Eclipse Mars WAS Plugin](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/V8.5/) . Not sure it still works. For Oxygen working version use [Eclipse Oxygen WAS Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v85x-developer-tools)